# Angular unit test with a resolver guard

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'd appreciate if someone could review what I'm missing, I have resolve guard on a route which gets the user which renders the name in the component.  I've created a test case for it but getting error of Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Component

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <span class="headline">{{user.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Data } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from './../../model/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.less']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User = new User();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data
      .subscribe(
        (data: Data) => {
          this.user = data['user'];
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Route

```
{ path: 'user-details', component: UserDetailsComponent, resolve: { user: UserResolver} },
```

Test

```
describe('Component: User', () => {
    let routeStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        routeStub = {
            data: null
        },
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                UserDetailsComponent
            ],
            imports: [       
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeStub }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    it('should render the user name', async(() => {

       var user = new User();
       user.name = "Alice";

        routeStub.data = { user: Observable.of(user) };

        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserDetailsComponent);
        let component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

        fixture.detectChanges();       
        let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(compiled.querySelector('span').textContent).toContain(user.name);
        });
    }));

});
```

Error

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
            at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/UserDetailsComponent.ngfactory.js:18:34)
            at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14909:21)
            at checkAndUpdateView (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14023:14)
            at callViewAction (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14369:21)
            at execComponentViewsAction (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14301:13)
            at checkAndUpdateView (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14024:5)
            at callWithDebugContext (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:15272:42)
            at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:14809:12)
            at ViewRef_.detectChanges (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:11793:22)
            at ComponentFixture._tick (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js?:208:32)
```

UPDATE: I also included the component ts file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ActivatedRoute` class has a `data` property which value that gets assigned with the resolver. I think you are not mocking that data object properly :

Try

```
providers: [
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useClass: class {
        data = Observable.of({user : new User({name: "Alice"})})
    }
]
```

OR

```
routeStub.data = Observable.of({user : new User({name: "Alice"})});
```

Comment: I get a different error when I do that "Failed: this.route.data.subscribe is not a function".  I included the component ts file.

Comment: My bad, I mixed up the definitions ... I have updated my answer.

Comment: That worked! Ty! Can you explain it a bit more, I'm not sure why I got so confused.

Comment: Nice! Your mistake was to not consider data as an Observable , data is the Observable and not what’s inside data

Comment: I see the problem, I think I read data wrong.  Initially I had _Observable.of(user)_ but I needed _Observable.of(user: user)_.  So data needed a user object of type user (it looks like it is an associative array) where I initially thought data was of type user.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I'm getting "Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)" on Angular 9, any idea ? (using import { Observable } from 'rxjs';)